# What is the best strategy to correct a referenced subdomain development website damaging my production seo

Tags: redirect, seo

Good morning,
I have a subdomain pointing to my development website and noticed that Google was recently referencing the dev pages.
I believe that this would harm the SEO of the production website with duplicate content and categories and was wondering what is the best strategy I could apply to correct it.
Shall I simply block the access.
Shall I set a .htaccess redirect for the whole or a DNS redirect.

Thank you for your advices.

I tried nothing so far

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [SEO: Full Redirect from Subdomain to Root Domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12402/seo-full-redirect-from-subdomain-to-root-domain)